# Exception during topic deletion when Kafka is hosted in Docker in Windows

Tags: windows, docker, apache-kafka

I host Kafka in Docker in Windows. [Wurstmeister/Kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/) docker image is used. Kafka data is stored in local Windows folder for persistency. Windows folder is mapped to Kafka docker image via Docker volumes. I can create topics, publish and consume messages. However when I try to delete topic I receive the following error:

```
 Error while deleting test-0 in dir /var/lib/kafka. (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
 java.io.IOException: Failed to rename log directory from /var/lib/kafka/test-0 to /var/lib/kafka/test-0.a81ff9700e4e4c3e8b20c6d949971b64-delete
 at kafka.log.LogManager.asyncDelete(LogManager.scala:671)
 at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$delete$1(Partition.scala:178)
 at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:217)
 at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:225)
 at kafka.cluster.Partition.delete(Partition.scala:173)
 at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplica(ReplicaManager.scala:341)
 at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$stopReplicas$2(ReplicaManager.scala:373)
 at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
 at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1417)
 at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
 at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:70)
 at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
 at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplicas(ReplicaManager.scala:371)
 at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleStopReplicaRequest(KafkaApis.scala:190)
 at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:104)
 at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:65)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could somebody help me to cope with this issue?

UPD: Below you can find contents of docker-compose file that I use to run Kafka:

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
    volumes:
      - ./zookeeper_data:/data
      - ./zookeeper_datalog:/datalog
  kafka:
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'false'
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    volumes:
      - ./kafka_logs:/var/lib/kafka
```

Comment: Does Kafka has not enough rights to to this operation? Pls. provide how do you start this container

Comment: I have a docker-compose file and start it with docker-compose up -d. The thing that I can create topic and publish messages, so Kafka has access to folder. I will update post with docker-compose file content.

Comment: You are mapping /var/lib/kafka to your host filesystem. Make sure user id of kafka (1000?) is allowed to write to your host path kafka_logs. Basically you need enought right on host for user with same id.

Comment: Ok. But as I said I can create topic and produce messages. So correct me if I'm wrong Kafka can write to kafka_logs?

Comment: @aholbreich I met same problem. May I ask how to grant enough right to delete the topic? I have tried to set the Zookeeper property of delete.topic.enable to true, it doesn't help. I also tried to run the Eclipse as en administration, still not works.

Comment: @Spider hi, maybe it worth separate question with config files and start command provied. Otherwise it's hard to graps what are you trying,

Comment: @Spider in my case the root cause was Javas' File.rename function. It doesn't work well in some cases in Windows. For details see this [Kafka issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3105). Issue is already resolved, but  seems it was not included into Kafka 1.0.0. So if you need reliable topic deletion you need to wait official release with fixed issue.

Comment: The PR https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/6329/commits is still open today.

Comment: This answer may help someone : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65070491/8888314

Comment: You can try to use a fix in [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/12331).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This issue still exists in Windows for Kafka ver 1.1.0 (kafka_2.12-1.1.0) when I try to delete the topic.

The topic gets marked for deletion and the Kafka server fails with java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when trying to rename the logs directory 'test-0'

Deleting the whole test-0 logs folder does not help.
Reinstalling the Kafka server does not help either - even after reinstalling, the info about the topic marked for deletion remains.

Took me a couple of hours to figure out that the info about the topic sits in the Zookeeper - in one of the log files!

#### Solution

Stop the Zookeeper process.
Go to your Zookeeper logs folder zookeeper-3.x.x\bin\zookeeper-3.x.xdata\version-2\ and delete the latest log.xx files.
Restart Zookeper.
Restart Kafka server.

Comment: can someone tell me where are zookeeper logs if I have the confluent version?

Comment: Issue still exists with Kafka 2.2 (faced using EmbeddedKafkaRule https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/src/reference/asciidoc/testing.adoc). Working well in Linux environment.

Comment: @ylka, it should be under the same folder where the Kafka's logs are. To be more specific, if you set "C:\tmp\kafka-logs" at server.properties, you will see the folder at "C:\tmp\zookeeper".

Comment: I'm using Kafka 2.3.1 and this solution works. Thanks, Brandon.

Comment: Where is this logs  folder on windows?? Because i can't find it. Btw my zookeeper runs in a docker container?

Comment: Where is this logs folder on windows 10? Because I can't find it. Menioned solution folder is not present.

Answer (score 5):

Delete version-2 from Zookeeper logs folder.
Delete all things in Kafka-logs folder.

Then restart the Zookeeper and Kafka server:

- `zookeeper-server-start.bat D:\kafka_2.11-2.4.1\config\zookeeper.properties`
- `kafka-server-start.bat D:\kafka_2.11-2.4.1\config\server.properties`

Comment: What's under 'version-2' folder, would that lead to data loss?

Answer (score 2):

Deletion of topic fails due to Java's File.rename function. It works differently in some cases in Windows environment (for example if file is in use). Kafka developers already changed this function to **Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback** (see this [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3105) for details), but seems it was not included into Kafka 2.11-0.11.0. So you need to work with Kafka version that has this fix. Hope this will helps.

Comment: In addition to @Oleksandr answer there is still an open issue related to file move/delete in windows environment: [KAFKA-1194](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1194)

Comment: The issue you linked to shows that it is fixed, however this is still a problem on windows. You can create a simple topic, and then immediately delete it and you get `ERROR Error while renaming dir for test-0 in log dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\tmp\kafka-logs\test-0 -> C:\tmp\kafka-logs\test-0.9b7da533fd9d4b1f8ad0e783f16ad1ee-delete`

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem

1.Stop both Kafka and Zookeeper processes. 

2.Delete all old log directories.

3.Change the log.dir to point to new directory in server.properties

4.Change the dataDir to point to new directory in zookeeper.properties

Then restart the Zookeeper and Kafka server:

C:\kafka_2.12-2.4.0> zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

C:\kafka_2.12-2.4.0> kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after reseting the credentials for my shared drive

Docker config > Shared Drives > Reset credentials [image: Docker Config]

Answer (score -2):

1, Change the log.dir with a new name in server.properties ->Kafka/config

log.dir=C:/Programs/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/kafka-test-logs

2, Remove the old log folder from C:/Programs/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.3.0/

3, Remove all logs and snapshot from C:\Programs\zookeeper\apache-zookeeper-3.5.5-bin\data
or delete the data folder where your log is stored

Additionally, I had an error when starting the consumer(Leader Not Available Kafka in Console Producer),

I added,

port = 9092
advertised.host.name = localhost

to the server.properties

Now am able to publish and consume messages